# $\mathscr{..}$ Expressions Fail to Render Properly in Org-Mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

Consider the expression `\mathscr{APPLE}`. This should render as follows:

> [image]

Yet in org-mode (using latex fragment previews), it renders as:

> [image]

Moreover, when *exporting*, matscr renders properly in HTML (when viewed in a browser), but *does not* render properly when exporting to pdf! How does one fix this behavior?

**EDIT:** Certain unicode characters also fail to render properly. For example $\phi$ renders fine but $ϕ$ does not render fine. I hope these errors are related so that fixing one fixes the other.

**EDIT2:** I get the following error message when using the settings suggested by Omar: [link](https://gist.github.com/georgewsinger/eea2ddf39c1bfef72c3c696dc0a81534).

**EDIT3:** The more specific error I'm getting (after checking `*Org Preview LaTeX Output*` buffer is:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Comment: Re: Edit2 error: have you installed `dvisvgm`?

Comment: Org depends on external facilities to do all this. You seem to expect to be able to customize org-mode and solve all the problems. That is not the case: you have to install all the external tools that are needed *AND* customize org-mode to use them. Just setting your expectations here.

Comment: @NickD: Yes, dvisvgm is installed.

Comment: There are two separate questions here which need separate answers: (a) rendering of mathscr (b) use of unicode-math.  Omar's answer works for the first case in a standard set-up.  The solution to (b) is more involved and less clear.

Comment: @George After EDIT3, I think you misunderstood what you were supposed to do with the `'(org-preview-latex-process-alist (quote ...))`. That's a *fragment* of a `custom-set-variables` form, so you need to wrap it like so: `(custom-set-variables '(org-preview-latex-process-alist (quote ...)))`.

Comment: @Omar: Thanks. I indeed had a silly error there. Now latex previewing is working but everything shows up as empty black boxes. When I export to pdf I get a new error as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/georgewsinger/eea2ddf39c1bfef72c3c696dc0a81534).

Comment: @George your expression renders correctly both in preview and export as .pdf if used in a math environment ```$\mathscr{APPLE}$```, by adding only the first header suggested by @Omar.

Answer (score 3):

The `\mathscr` problem is simply that Org mode LaTeX doesn't by
default load the LaTeX package that provides that command. Just add
`#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{mathrsfs}` to your Org file and that
should fix both preview and PDF export.

As for getting unicode math to work, you need, again, to load a
package (so add `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{unicode-math}` to your
Org file), but there's a wrinkle this time: the `unicode-math` package
doesn´t work with `pdflatex`, only `xetex` or `luatex`, so you
additionally need to customize the `org-latex-pdf-process` variable (for PDF export) and the `org-preview-latex-process-alist` and `org-preview-latex-default-process` variables (for LaTeX preview) to
choose one of those compilers.

Comment: `(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luatex)` yields error "cond: Unknown conversion process luatex for LaTeX fragments". Am I not using it correctly?

Comment: Unfrotunately, it's quite a bit more complicated than that @George. :( Try the setting suggested in this [Emacs SE answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33172/2221).

Comment: I get the following error message when using these settings: [link](https://gist.github.com/georgewsinger/eea2ddf39c1bfef72c3c696dc0a81534).

Comment: @George: I got the same error message. :( The process also left a buffer named `*Org Preview LaTeX Output*` that contained the message: "DVI error: DVI format 6 not supported". I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254864/set-dvi-version-output-in-xelatex) related to that error message.

Comment: After checking `*Org Preview LaTeX Output*` it appears I'm getting a different error. See my post above edited.

Comment: @George, I forgot to ask: is the problem with mathscr solved? And you only need to get unicode math working now?

Comment: I think they're both unsolved. Right now I'm unable to render to LaTeX at all with these settings (I'd have to track down my original settings to see if one was solved and the other wasn't; if you need me to do that though to answer this question properly LMK).