# Why is latex preview and latex to html export via dvisvgm not working in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, preview-latex

I read [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30341/how-do-i-customize-the-process-that-gets-triggered-in-org-preview-latex-fragment) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568410/configure-org-mode-to-use-lualatex) question along with the documentation of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` pulled up by `C-h v org-preview-latex-process-alist RET`. Alright, I have an idea about what to do. I put this in my `init.el` under `(use-package org ... :init)`

```lisp
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
  '("xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
    "xelatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"))
  (setq xdvsvgm
        '(xdvsvgm
          :programs ("xelatex" "dvisvgm")
          :description "xdv > svg"
          :message "you need to install the programs: xelatex and dvisvgm."
          :use-xcolor t
          :image-input-type "xdv"
          :image-output-type "svg"
          :image-size-adjust (1.7 . 1.5)
          :latex-compiler ("xelatex -no-pdf -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O")))
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist xdvsvgm)
    (setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'xdvsvgm))
```

Then I try `C-c C-e h h` to export to html but I get,

`org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexlUjxgz.xdv" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘xdvsvgm’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.`

I don't understand why the xdv file is not produced. My hunch is that there is something wrong with the command `xelatex -no-pdf -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f`.

Could someone help?

Here is a minimal document to test it,

```
#+TITLE: Title Here
#+AUTHOR: Author Name
#+OPTIONS: tex:xdvsvgm

#+BEGIN_export latex
\begin{align*}
    n &= \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{2} \\
      &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1
\end{align*}
#+END_export
```

Comment: The two links at the top are to the *same* question: can you fix that?

Comment: The usual debugging technique for such problems is to execute the command on the command line and see if it works as you expect. If not, fix the command; if yes, fix the linkage between Org mode and the command.

Comment: Do you mean `C-c C-x C-l` to get a LaTeX preview? Exporting will just skip the latex secttion altogether since it's not HTML.

Comment: If you try to export the above to HTML, the `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex ... #+END_EXPORT` block should not be processed at all: you are saying "This block should only be exported to LaTeX (or PDF since that goes through LaTeX) - any other export should omit it". Are you sure you are exporting it to HTML?

Comment: Okay to be honest, I am not that fluent in org-mode ways. I am using that latex begin end code block because then I get better syntax highlighting (AucTex like). And, it exports to Latex code without actually exporting the begin and end wrap. I fixed the links.

Comment: Also as per [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html#Math-formatting-in-HTML-export), "If you prefer, you can also request that LaTeX fragments are processed into small images that will be inserted into the browser page".

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I solved the issue with some insight that if the command was failing to produce `/tmp/orgtexlUjxgz.xdv` then there must be a `/tmp/orgtexlUjxgz.log` with detail about the issue. And, sure enough, looking at `/tmp/orgtexlUjxgz.log` I realised that I was missing a package and resolving that fixed the `org-toggle-latex-fragment`.